# How to test activity.finishAffinity() in Roboelectric?

Tags: android, android-activity, robolectric

I am trying to write Roboelectric test for **activity.finishAffinity()** method instead of **activity.finish()**. I tried asserting **activity.isFinishing()** to true but I am getting **AssertionError**.

what will be probable solution for this?